# SQL date format conversion from INT(yyyymmdd) type to date(mm/dd/yyyy)

Tags: sql, date-formatting, date-conversion

I have a table with datekey column values(20120728,20120728...) in format of `yyyymmdd` as int type, I need to make them into date format of `mm/dd/yyyy` while writing select statement.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: googled "ms sql date formatting"?

Answer (score 19):

```
DECLARE @date int;
SET @date = 20131107

SELECT CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(8), @date), 112)
```

Comment: hi, thanks for reply, after declaration you provided value, but i cant do that as i wil get lots of values from table

Comment: i made it to format of yyyy-mm-dd, i need to convert that to mm/dd/yyyy format, can you please help in this

Comment: this one works but i need column name in place of getdate(), thats throwing error

Comment: Where does the 112 come from?

Answer (score 10):

Please Try This

```
DECLARE @date int;
SET @date = 20120728    
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20), CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(8), @date), 112),110)as datetime
```

Comment: hi, this one is giving ans with - separated date i need adte in the format separated by '/', thanks for your reply, wil post my ans, it wont allow my reply to my question now

Comment: thanks that result can be separated by '/' ; you can place 103 insteed of 110