# Format date from yyyymmdd to Y-m-d with PHP

Tags: php, date

This question shows how to do it with SQL ([SQL date format conversion from INT(yyyymmdd) type to date(mm/dd/yyyy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829818/sql-date-format-conversion-from-intyyyymmdd-type-to-datemm-dd-yyyy)), how can I do it with PHP?

I want to convert dates from something like 20141127 to 2014-11-27 and I don't knwo if there is a build in function, or any usage of the php dates function to achieve this.

Thank you

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php and http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: takes less time to do a search than type this question

Comment: This is the most basic sort of string manipulation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use strtotime() to convert a string containing a date into a Unix timestamp:

```
<?php
// both lines output 813470400
echo strtotime("19951012"), "\n",
     strtotime("12 October 1995");
?>
```

You can pass the result as the second parameter to date() to reformat the date yourself:

```
<?php
// prints 1995 Oct 12
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("19951012"));
?>
```

Comment: It is so simple I feel bad now for asking. Thank you